# Mocking read-only Flux store property in TypeScript

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm creating an app using React, Flux, and TypeScript. I'm testing using Karma and Jasmine.

I have a Store, like this:

```
class MemberStore {
    private _members:Member[];
    public get members():Member[] { return this._members; }
}
```

As with all Flux stores, data is read-only and modified through action handlers (not shown), not setters.

I would like to mock this data store in a unit test of code that depends on `MemberStore`. However, since `members` is read-only I cannot do something like this:

```
var mockMemberStore:MemberStore = jasmine.createSpyObj("MemberStore");
mockMemberStore.members = [/*mock members*/];
```

The above code actually emits working JS, since `mockMemberStore` is not actually an instance of `MemberStore` but a Jasmine spy object (and `createSpyObj` returns `any`). <s>However, it generates a compile-error on `mockMemberStore.members = []` because it's a read-only property.</s>

> **EDIT:** So it turns out I was mis-reading the error, and it was **not** this code that gave an error. It was not a *compile* error, it's a *runtime* error. Surprisingly, TSC doesn't care if I assign a value to `members` at compile time, even though
>   it's read-only. In the above example I replace `MemberStore`
>   completely with a jasmine SpyObj, which works. If instead I simply try to
>   `spyOn` a real version of `MemberStore`, that's when I see a runtime error that
>   `members` cannot be assigned. [Example](http://bit.ly/1YnvDil)

I could change it to `var mockMemberStore:any`, or use casting like `(<any> mockMemberStore).members = []`, but then the compiler doesn't see `members` as a reference to `ModelStore/members` so all static type checking is lost (and things like "find references" and "refactor/rename" don't work). What is the approach to use here?

Comment: what do you mean by "static references" (to `ModelStore/members`)?

Comment: I guess I just mean references. A reference that can be statically analyzed by the compiler, so that for example refactoring will pick it up as a reference to `MemberStore/members`. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are useful for this:

```
interface IMemberStore {
    members: Member[];
}

class MemberStore implements IMemberStore {
    private _members:Member[];
    public get members():Member[] { return this._members; }
}

class MockMemberStore implements IMemberStore {
    members: Member[];
}
```

Use `IMemberStore` in most of your application, use `MemberStore` as the implementation, and use `MockMemberStore` in your unit tests.

Comment: I like this solution, but I guess it's basically making the `MemberStore` properties not look read-only. However it turns out TSC doesn't care if you only have a getter, [it allows assignment of read-only properties](http://bit.ly/1YnvDil) and it's JS in `use strict` that throws an error.

Comment: @Aaron you could enforce readonly by instead using a method: `interface IMemberStore { getMembers(): Member[]; }` and making the array private in the implementation. That's usually what I do.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, using `getMembers` is probably the safest approach. Then I can `spyOn` the real thing *or* create a `SpyObj` replacement and in both cases just use `and.returnValue()` to mock the data.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to write:

```
(mockMemberStore as any).members = [""];
```

This will not change the type of any future references to `mockMemberStore`. Because this is a unit test, the code does not need to be as perfect as it usually is. The important thing is that it will fail if you introduce an error, and in this case, it will fail: if you perform an invalid refactor, `renamedMembers` will no longer be set and the test should blow up, and you will be able to fix it.

This is not ideal, since you do lose find-usages, but it's not as bad as it often is in other languages (mocking readonly objects is notoriously cumbersome).

Comment: It's a good point, for the sake of testing this isn't such a crime. However it turns out I misread the error: it was not actually TSC complaining at compile-time, but JS giving an error at runtime. It was a surprise to me that [TSC actually allows the assignment of a read-only property and it's JS that throws an error](http://bit.ly/1YnvDil).

Comment: @Aaron with this answer you need to set the array itself and not set the accessor: `(mockMemberStore as any)._members = [""];` (@mk. you might want to update the answer)

Comment: @DavidSherret Actually, that would be true if the `MemberStore` was real, but its a jasmine SpyObj, so no `_members` or `members` getter actually exists. It turns out this produces no compile error (surprisingly) or runtime error. The original error I saw was a runtime error when `MemberStore` *was* the real thing (cause I used `spyOn` instead of `createSpyObj`), in which case setting `_members` would be correct.